# GA Query parameters gone when using PageType?

Tags: google-analytics

On a page `/user/survey` I'm triggering a PageView event with PageType `UserSurvey`.

In GA I see this page views as follows: `/user/survey+UserSurvey`

However, users land on this page with different query parameters depending on the campaign they were interested in. For example:

- `/user/survey/?email_campaign=1`
- `/user/survey/?offline_campaign=1`
- etc.

I want to see only users that came with `email_campaign` query parameter. How do I do that?

I can't find these query parameters anywhere in GA even when trying to segment the audience by page URL. Are query parameters gone and all page views will be grouped together when pages with different query parameters are using the same PageType? I can't believe some of the URL data could be gone this way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related my be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use UTM parameters to segment the audience.

For example:
/user/survey/?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=campaign1
/user/survey/?utm_medium=offline&cammpaign1